# Удалить все символы кроме букв и цифр

Tags: php

Как удалить все символы кроме букв и цифр из php переменной?

```
<?php
   $lp = "asd23f№21";
   echo $lp;
?>
```

Comment: `$lp ="";` ? :D

Comment: @Suvitruf ну почти)

Comment: `preg_replace('/[^0-9a-zA-Z]/', '', $lp);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
preg_replace('/[^0-9a-zA-Z]/', '', $lp);
```